# UDF or standard IF function for date range?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, iteration, udf

I am trying to create a range from numbers in a column, and create a range. For example,

```
column F: 
1899 
1912 
1915 
1918 
1929 
1934 
1935 
1936
...
```

So as soon as 1934, 1935, 1936 sequence starts, it would capture 1934 and iterate through until the difference isn't 1.

The result for this example would be:

```
1934 - 1936.
```

Once I create these date ranges, I would use text to columns by the "-" delimiter to create begin and end date columns.

The difficulty in this is comparing another column and making sure the dates are based on a particular title.

So: IF(Title 1 = Title 2, (IF date 2 - date 1 = 1, increment to check date 3 - date 2 = 1, otherwise = date 1)).

I could try to nest many IF statements, but that would get nasty, plus no idea how many dates to compare per title.

Iteration seems like it would be much easier by creating a sub or UDF in VBA, but I haven't found any examples on here (or elsewhere) that may be helpful.

Comment: You could do this with [excel-formula] but you will have a problem if the 1 day sequencing stops and then starts up again. Probably better as a UDf with an optional parameter that tells it which group of 1-day-date-separations to use.

Comment: Are you already done with _"create a range from numbers in a column"_ issue?  Plus I don't get what's the _"comparing another column"_ thing: would you mind adding an example?

Comment: *creating a sub or UDF in VBA, but I haven't found any examples on here* -- the best thing you can do at this point is *try to create one*, and revise your question with that in mind, letting us know what problems/errors you're encountering. There's usually not a ready-made solution to individual problems, it's all about modifying/adapting and using the built-ins and object model to your advantage, to solve your specific problem.

Comment: The "comparing another column" is essentially, in my mind, like using a key. So for example: Title 1: dates 1899 1912 1915; Title 2:  1918 1929 1934 1935 1936

Comment: If you get an answer to this as a formula for the start and stop of the first group of one-day-sequences are you going to immediately ask how to get the second group?

Comment: Maybe not immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job, it will take cells in column F and print your output in column G. If there is a range of years (ex: 1934-1935-1936), it will put it in a single cell as a string.

```
Sub range_dates()
Dim cel As Range
Dim iRow As Long, n As Long
Dim title As String, nextTitle As String
iRow = 2
n = 0
For i = 2 To 15
    Set cel = Cells(i, "F")
    title = Cells(i, "E").Value
    nextTitle = Cells(i + 1, "E").Value
    diff = Cells(i + 1, "F").Value - cel.Value

    If diff = 1 And title = nextTitle Then
        firstDate = cel.Value - n
        n = n + 1
    Else
        Cells(iRow, "H").Value = cel.Value
        Cells(iRow, "G").Value = title
        If n > 0 Then
            Cells(iRow, "H") = "'" & firstDate & " - " & cel.Value
            n = 0
        End If
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I do know this code is not the most optimized, but as of now it's the one i have to share. Feel free to improve it :)

EDIT: I added the title conditions and changed the output to prevent excel from changing the string to a date format

Comment: This is what I need. I have worked through everything else everyone provided, but this seems to be the closest representation of what I'm looking for. The only addition I am trying to add to what you have is something like: If diff = 1 "And Cell D1=D2...D2=D3...etc, otherwise, move to next D with a new title"

Comment: I think i figured out your title thing.. see edit. It will verify if you have the same title (column E) and print an output of titles and years

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the start and stop of the first group of one-day-sequences is not too difficult with the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF). In H2:I2 as a standard formula,

```
'in H2
=INDEX(F$2:F$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$14)/((F$3:F$16-$F$2:$F$15)=1), 1))    
'in I2
=INDEX(INDEX(F:F, MATCH(H2,F:F, 0)):F$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$14)/((INDEX(F:F, MATCH(H2,F:F, 0)+1):F$16-INDEX(F:F, MATCH(H2,F:F, 0)):$F$15)<>1), 1))
```

[image: first_group_one_day]

If you wanted to combine them then substitute all references to H2 in the second formula with the first formula.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you need a way to get dates "ranges" while I still don't get the "comparing another column" thing

as for the first issue you may try this (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim fictitiousRng As Range, area As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim iCell As Long

    With Worksheets("numbers") '<--| reference your worksheet (change "numbers" to your actual worksheet name)
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("F")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<-- reference its column "F" non blank cells with numeric data only
            With .Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count) '<--| reference referenced range offsetted 1 colum to the right
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=""A"" & RC6" '<--| fill its content with a "fictitiuous" range address by placing an "A" in front of corresponding number in column "F"
                Set fictitiousRng = Range("B1") ' set a initial range for 'fictitiousRng' not to bother for subsequent first call of 'Union()' method
                For Each area In .Areas '<--| loop through referenced range areas (i.e. cells "groups")
                    For iCell = 2 To area.Cells.Count '<--| loop through current area cells
                        Set fictitiousRng = Union(fictitiousRng, Range(area.Cells(iCell, 1).value)) '<--| update 'fictitiousRng' with the cell corresponding to the current fictitious range address
                    Next iCell
                Next area
                arr = Split(Replace(Replace(Intersect(fictitiousRng, Columns(1)).Address(False, False), "A", ""), ":", " - "), ",") '<--| get the fictitious range address, remove "A"s and substitute "." with "-" and then write final "numbers" into an array
                .ClearContents '<-- clear referenced range, i.e. cells with fictitious addresses
                .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr) + 1).value = Application.Transpose(arr) '<--| write array content into referenced range cells starting from its first cell
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

it writes the dates "ranges" in the first *not used* column of the same column "F" dates worksheet

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having the formula broken out into several columns, here's an `IF()` statement example on how to extract the Begin & End Years:

[image: Find the beginning and ending year range - Excel formula example]

`=IF(B13>1,"",IF(B14<2,IF(C12="",A13,C12),IF(ISNUMBER(C12),C12&"-"&A14,A13&"-"&A14)))`

**Explanation**

Column B - Find difference between years

Column C - Elegant `nested IF()` formula ;)

Column D - `Left()` 4 character if length is > 4

Column E - `Right()` 4 character if length is > 4